# Is there a way to store and display HTML with CSS to achieve text formatting in Android?

Tags: android, html, text, webview, formatting

I'm creating a note taking app for Android and i would like the user to be able to format their text, i.e. bold, different text sizes.

What I would like to know is how can I do this bearing in mind the text will have to be store-able in a database.

Can i use a web view with a string of HTML i pull from the database and a custom defined CSS to style it on the user end?

I also know there is some sort of formatting class in Android but im unsure of how it work, im not convinced it would be easy to store the formatting information.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Spannable text. See android.text.*. I think you should store the text in HTML markup. Also take a look at 
http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/commontasks.html#selectingtext

Comment: Thanks, ill have a look at it when i can. This task has been put on the back burner for a while.